# Random forest for classifying, cannot reshape array of size 16884608 into shape (4221152,3)

Tags: python, classification, random-forest, image-classification

I am applying one script using random forest for object detection on optical image. I use tif as image format. I use this script, below, but I have always te same error, and I don't know as resolved it. The original script is here [link](https://ceholden.github.io/open-geo-tutorial/python/chapter_5_classification.html).

```
from __future__ import print_function, division
from osgeo import gdal, gdal_array
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
gdal.UseExceptions()
gdal.AllRegister()

# Read in our image and ROI image
img_RS = 'image_satellite.TIF'
roi_ds = gdal.Open('landuse_roi.tif')

# load image data
img_ds = gdal.Open(img_RS, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
img = np.zeros((img_ds.RasterYSize, img_ds.RasterXSize, img_ds.RasterCount),
               gdal_array.GDALTypeCodeToNumericTypeCode(img_ds.GetRasterBand(1).DataType))
for b in range(img.shape[2]):
    img[:, :, b] = img_ds.GetRasterBand(b + 1).ReadAsArray()
    
roi = roi_ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray().astype(np.uint8)
```

The raster dataset features by 0 and 1, whereas 0 identifies no data and 1 correct data. Before the raster was one shapefile where 1 identifies polygons that they have to classified. And here it is not clear, why there are 3 labels, infact the result is 0, 1 and 3, when I have only two classes.

```
labels = np.unique(roi[roi > 0])
```

We will need a "X" matrix containing our features, and a "y" array containing our labels
These will have n_samples rows.
In other languages  would need to allocate these and them loop to fill them, but NumPy can be faster.

```
X = img[roi >= 0, :]  # include 8th band, which is Fmask, for now
y = roi[roi >= 0]
# Mask out clouds, cloud shadows, and snow using Fmask
clear = X[:, 1] <= 4
X = X[clear, :4]  # we can ditch the Fmask band now
y = y[clear]
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, oob_score=True, max_leaf_nodes=20, verbose=1, n_jobs=-1)
X = np.nan_to_num(X)
rf2 = rf.fit(X, y)
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['truth'] = y
df['predict'] = rf.predict(X)
```

Take our full image, ignore the Fmask band, and reshape into long 2d array (nrow * ncol, nband) for classification

```
new_shape = (img.shape[0] * img.shape[1], img.shape[2] - 1)
img_as_array = img[:, :, :np.int_(img.shape[2])].reshape(new_shape)
```

Here I have this error: `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 16884608 into shape (4221152,3)`

Comment: Can you share in what line it gives the error? Or the full error code. Usually it says in which line of your code is the problem, and that will help a lot with the debugging

Comment: On the last line I have error "img_as_array = img[:, :, :np.int_(img.shape[2])].reshape(new_shape)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading through the docs of [np.reshape()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html), it says that

> the shape should be compatible with the original shape.

As I understand it, it means that if you have an array of 3*4 (12 values) the new shape should also have 9 values, so you can respahe a 3*4 to a 12*1 or a 4*3 or a 6*2, but you cannot reshape into a 3*3 (it has 9 values, you'd lose info).

In your case, the error says

> cannot reshape array of size 16884608 into shape (4221152,3)

If we do the math: `1688468` is not equal in number to `4221152*3 = 12663456`

In the docs it says that one shape dimension can be -1 (and the function will fill that up with what it needs to be)

> One shape dimension can be -1. In this case, the value is inferred from the length of the array and remaining dimensions.

Maybe you can use that to solve the problem